# Sample size vs F1-score, which is more important (small sample size)

Tags: classification, sample-size, accuracy, small-sample, multi-class

I work in a filed were there are many publications based on classifiers trained on small samples sizes (but large amount of features). In most cases the sample size can only be increased by a few instances based on the cumbersome annotation process.

I built a classifier for a multi-classification problem, that has a micro-F1 score of 0.8 based on a cross validation performed on approx. 2000 samples. There is a published study, where they also reached an micro-F1 score of 0.8, but their sample size was approx. 1000 samples.

Unfortunately the identical 1000 sample data set can not be used (it is nor public). Can I still make an argument, that my classifier might perform better on new data, since the training size was twice as much ?

Are there any studies available were performance is compared with sample size for small sample classification.

Comment: +1 but also the obligatory comment about proper scoring rules as opposed to the threshold-based F1 score: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/469059/247274

Comment: I am not completely sure how the comment is related to the question, I mean, if one is bound to a certain scoring rule / metric for comparability reasons, one does not really have a choice right ?

Comment: You have a point about comparability to earlier work. However, some people (me included) will argue that if that earlier work relies on F1 scores, then to that degree, it is flawed, and newer work should use better tools. That said, I do not think we can answer your question, since we do not know anything about how comparable the two datasets are. Answers might go either way.